# How do I identify my IP address on bitnodes?

Tags: nodes, bitnodes

I have supposedly successfully setup a node using the Bitcoin core, but when I go to bitnodes to remotely see if the node is communicating with the network, bitnodes says i am unreachable. Bitcoin core disagrees. How can I find my node's unique address? Using cmd to run a netstat query shows me an ipv4 address that is also unsearchable with a fluid port range (49800-49950).

Something tells me I know just barely enough about networking to be dangerous.

Comment: Are you behind NAT or a firewall?

Comment: using windows 8.1 pro and bitcoin core is listed as an exception

Comment: Are you behind Nat?

Comment: ah, perfect evidence of my lack of knowledge of networking. am i behind a NAT, yes because my computer is connecting to the internet through a router that identifies my computer with a 10.x.x.x IPv4 address?

Comment: Yes that's a private address range. Try setting up port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a NAT network (192.168.****  or 10.*******) then use port forward in your router/modem and open 8333 in your firewalls.

Not behind NAT? Check all your firewalls and add a 8333 exception when needed