# v0.13.1 wallet - connect failed: Network is unreachable (101)

Tags: bitcoin-core, network

Noob here.  Ran the core wallet on my Linux PC and looking for help as to why it is not working after syncing up the history of blockchain Tx's.  Is this likely my router not passing port 8333 packets, or something else?  thanks!

```
2016-12-15 13:39:52 Pre-allocating up to position 0xe00000 in rev00709.dat
2016-12-15 13:39:52 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000021ab2f093924ee05d43c228c2f6ab84414d7b77bef0ca18 height=443582 version=0x20000000 log2_work=85.680045 tx=179248787 date='2016-12-15 13:40:26' progress=1.000000 cache=175.8MiB(93812tx) warning='2 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'
2016-12-15 13:39:54 ProcessMessages: advertising address 179.125.21.234:8333
2016-12-15 13:39:54 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.13.1/: version 70014, blocks=443582, us=179.125.21.234:58800, peer=21
2016-12-15 13:39:54 AdvertiseLocal: advertising address 179.125.21.234:8333
2016-12-15 13:41:31 connect() to [2001:0:9d38:6ab8:3c33:1df8:ab64:a421]:8333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
2016-12-15 13:41:59 connect() to 114.254.131.229:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111)
2016-12-15 13:43:00 connect() to [2001:0:9d38:6ab8:249a:276e:a1e9:fc4b]:8333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
2016-12-15 13:46:38 connect() to [2001:0:9d38:90d7:2068:fbff:2776:17b5]:8333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
2016-12-15 13:48:46 connect() to [2001:0:5ef5:79fd:344e:fda:b3e8:2a0d]:8333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
2016-12-15 13:53:08 ProcessMessages: advertising address 179.125.21.234:8333
2016-12-15 13:53:08 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.13.1/: version 70014, blocks=443582, us=179.125.21.234:48796, peer=22
2016-12-15 13:53:08 AdvertiseLocal: advertising address 179.125.21.234:8333
2016-12-15 13:53:25 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000004cfce5b4e88c754daa10165a2495fbc9893a8fb054f938 height=443583 version=0x30000000 log2_work=85.680076 tx=179251601 date='2016-12-15 13:53:36' progress=1.000000 cache=217.3MiB(104890tx) warning='3 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'
```

Comment: Also when I try to confirm my node on this page :  https://bitnodes.21.co
It says "179.125.21.234:8333 is unreachable."

Comment: .... and crickets.  Nobody can help me?

Comment: eh, think I found it.  My router using NAT...
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38057/how-do-i-identify-my-ip-address-on-bitnodes

"If you are on a NAT network (192.168.**** or 10.*******) then use port forward in your router/modem and open 8333 in your firewalls.

Not behind NAT? Check all your firewalls and add a 8333 exception when needed"

Comment: Brad, your conclusion is correct. The most likely explanation is NAT. Your bitcoin node is advertising its external (NATed) IP address, but your router is not forwarding incoming connections back to your Linux PC. You need a forwarding rule